# Sql substring function with variable length parametres

Tags: sql, substring, amazon-redshift

I got next error message:

```
SQL Error [500310] [42725]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.substring(character varying, smallint, smallint) is not unique;
```

when trying execute query:

```
select SUBSTRING(a.string,b.index,b.length)
  from a
  JOIN
  b
  ON a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd and i think you have found a bug! its not happy with smallint.

But you can get around it easily like this

```
select SUBSTRING(a.string,b.index::integer,b.length::integer)
  from a
  JOIN
  b
  ON a.id=b.id
```